# UseContext React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

how can I use UseContext to make this const '' data '' accessible throughout my project? I'm trying to implement but I can't. It doesn't have to be with UseContext, it was just a way that I researched

```
import api from '../../services/api';
import React, {useContext} from 'react';


export default async function getItems() {
  try {
    const data = await api.get("/list-results");
    return data;
    
  } catch (error) {
    return error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create yourself a context:

```
const MyContext = React.createContext(defaultValue);
```

Then call your getItems() and store the result in a state and pass it to your context provider:

```
const [storedData, setStoredData] = useState<MyData | null>(null);
useEffect(() => {
    getItems().then((data) => setStoredData(data));
}, []);
if (!storedData) return <div>Loading</div>;
return <MyContext.Provider value={}><MyApp/> </MyContext.Provider>;
```

Ideally do some more error handling in there.

And finally, get your context using useContext in a component somewhere in MyApp:

```
const data = useContext(MyContext);
```

Code is untested and should be seen as pseudo-code.